# FireDAC - DataExplorer - connection to a 2.5 Firebird DB

Tags: firebird, firedac

I need to make a connection to a Firebird 2.5 DB, using DataExplrer from FireDAC. Anyone knows how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the FireDAC documentation? If so, specify the problem you are having.

Comment: @Mark. I indeed looked at the FireDAC documentation. Turns out that is very poor. I could not find the subject I'm looking for, that is, the DataExplorer. The Delphi version I'm using is XE4 Enterprise. That was the first Delphi version were the FireDAc was embedded into the IDE. Before that, was AnyDAC. When I open the DataExplorer, Firebird, is not listed on DBMS list. I searched for a tip at the FireDAC documentation as how to connect to a Firebird database, but none. I searched at the Web and none. I hoped somone has a clue about this issue at stackoverflow.

Comment: I know nothing about Delphi, but this doesn't help: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/firedac/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=Connect_to_Interbase_or_Firebird.html ?

Comment: @Mark. Thanks for the tip. That was the documentation I've searched, as I told you before, but does not clarify how to make a Firebird connection using the DataExplorer, wich is kind of a DBMS, as IBExpert, for instance. Thanks anyway.